# A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$

Tags: functions

Does there exist a non trivial function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ ?

Comment: Yeah !! Also the one which @Nilan gave

Comment: That's trivial...

Comment: @Nilan what would be the functional inverse of that function. would the inverse even be a function?

Comment: it's not invertible

Comment: Yes! you are right.

Comment: @cirpis: Linear functions are not solutions.

Comment: See also: [Is there a function whose inverse is exactly the reciprocal of the function, that is $f^{-1} = \frac{1}{f}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585394)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least the functional equation can't hold for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that plugging in $x = 0$ implies
$$
f^{-1}(0) = \frac{1}{f(0)} \Rightarrow 0 = f\left(\frac{1}{f(0)}\right)
$$
so in particular $f$ attains value $0$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. But now
$$
f^{-1}(c) = \frac{1}{f(c)} = \frac{1}{0},
$$
so there is no such function.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ continuous. Then $f$, being invertible, is increasing or decreasing. If it is increasing, $f^{-1}(x)$ is increasing, while $[f(x)]^{-1}$ is decreasing. If it is decreasing, $f^{-1}(x)$ is decreasing, while $[f(x)]^{-1}$ is increasing. So there exists no solution among continuous functions. In fact, any solution would have to be everywhere discontinuous, or continuous at only a finite set of points.