# Is there a function whose inverse is exactly the reciprocal of the function, that is $f^{-1} = \frac{1}{f}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is there a function whose inverse is exactly the reciprocal of the function?
That is $f^{-1} = \frac{1}{f}$.

We know that the inverse of a function is not necessarily equal to its reciprocal in general.

Comment: @Mr.MBB, you should edit your question to include that functional equation.

Comment: $f(x)=x^i=e^{i\log x}$.

Comment: It should be $f(x) = x^i = e^{iln x}, x>0$. Good example

Comment: $\ln x = \log x$ for any proper mathematician unless specified otherwise.

Comment: A great article on exactly this topic: *When Does $f^{-1} = 1/f$?* by R. Cheng, A. Dasgupta, B. R. Ebanks, L. F. Kinch, L. M. Larson, and R. B. McFadden, in the American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 105, Number 8 in October 1998.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260278

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The complex function $f(x) = x^{\pm i}$ satisfies this property.

Its inverse is $f^{-1}(x) = x^{\mp i}$ since $f^{-1}\circ f(x) = \left(x^{\pm i}\right)^{\mp i} = x$.

One can see that $1/f(x) = x^{\mp i} = f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Formally this certainly works, but "$x^{i}$" isn't a (single-valued) function, and the law of exponents $(x^{a})^{b} = x^{ab}$ isn't unconditionally true for complex exponentiation.

Answer (score 41):

Assuming that the function maps $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ and is *differentiable*, the answer is **no.**

Here's why.  In order for a continuous function to be invertible, it must be strictly [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) (monotone increasing or monotone decreasing).  In fact:

CLAIM 1:  If $f$ is an increasing function, then $f^{-1}$ is too.

PROOF:  This is a straightforward, standard calculation using the chain rule and the fact that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ for all $x$:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(f^{-1}(x)) = f'(f^{-1}(x)) \cdot (f^{-1})'(x)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{d}{dx} x = 1
$$
so
$$
(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.
$$
According to this last expression, the signs of $(f^{-1})'$ and $f'$ are the same.

CLAIM 2:  If $f$ is an increasing function, then $(1/f)(x)$ is decreasing.

PROOF:  Calculate the derivative using the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{f(x)} = -\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}.
$$
Since the denominator is positive, the signs of $(1/f)'$ and $f'$ must be opposite.

---

Comment: +1. As a side note, the claim 1 is also true for non differentiable functions, whereas the claim 2 is true for non differentiable functions *whose sign is constant*. Of course, the initial claim, that an invertible function is monotonic is true for continuous functions, but not for non continuous functions.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I couldn't see how to relax the differentiability in the second claim, and the proof of the first claim is *straightforward* with that hypothesis.

Comment: The second claim is elementary: the reciprocal function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$  on $(0,\infty)$, so, if $f$ is increasing and has a constant sign, then the composition $1/f=g\circ f$ is decreasing. (To prove this last claim, remember that "increasing=order-preserving" and "decreasing=order-reversing".

Comment: There is also an elementary proof of the first claim: assume that $y_1<y_2$ are two elements of the range of $f$. Then $y_1=f(x_1)$ and $y_2=f(x_2)$ for some $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the domain of $f$. We cannot have $x_1=x_2$ since $f$ is one-to-one. If $x_1> x_2$, then $y_1=f(x_1)> f(x_2)=y_2$ since $f$ is increasing. It is a contradiction with $y_1<y_2$, so $f^{-1}(y_1)=x_1<x_2=f^{-1}(y_2)$.

Comment: Your proof certainly works but there can be no function defined on point $0$ that satisfies this equation, because if it was possible then the inverse function will equal to $0$ at some point which is not possible by equation. So the domain of our function cannot be all real numbers.

Answer (score 26):

It is possible for this to be satisfied in $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ everywhere except $ 0$.

$$ f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      -x & x \geq 0 \\
      -{x}^{-1} & x \lt 0 \\
   \end{cases}
$$

EDIT: User Slade [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585412/155149) whether it is possible in $\mathbb{R}^+ \to\mathbb{R}^+$.  I've constructed a solution.

Let $ g(x) $ be a bijective function from $ \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right] $ to $ \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right) $.

Then the following function satisfies $ f^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{f} $:

$$  f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      g(x) & 0 \lt x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
      \dfrac{1} {g^{-1}(x)} & \frac{1}{2} \lt x \lt 1 \\
      1 & x = 1 \\
      g^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}) & 1 \lt x \lt 2 \\
      \dfrac{1} {g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} & 2 \leq x \\
\end{cases}
$$

EDIT 2: Here's an example of such a $g$:

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases}
      \dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac 1 {n+1} & x = \dfrac 1  n, n \in \Bbb{N} \\
      \dfrac 1 2 + x & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Excellent !!!  I like this example.

Comment: Could you supply an example of such a function $g$, please?

Answer (score 20):

This is by no means a complete answer, but it is a bit long for a comment.

If $f\circ 1/f = 1/f \circ f = x$, we have the equations:

$$f(1/f(x)) = x$$

$$f(f(x)) = 1/x$$

In particular, $f$ is a [half-iterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) of $1/x$.  Note that there cannot possibly be a solution defined at $x=0$.

One observation is that if $f$ satisfies the above equations, $1/f$ does as well.  So if we could somehow prove that there was at most one solution to the above equations, then we could conclude that $f=1/f$ and arrive at a contradiction.

This problem deserves a very clear specification about what domain $f$ should be defined on, whether it should be continuous, and so forth.  For example, the answer $x^i$ works as a function on the complex plane, but it can only be a continuous function away from a branch cut.  And the much more interesting question of whether there exists such a function $\mathbb{R}^+ \to\mathbb{R}^+$ is still open.

Answer (score 15):

For definiteness, let $X$ and $Y$ denote non-empty sets of complex numbers and let $f:X \to Y$ be a bijection whose inverse $f^{-1}:Y \to X$ is the reciprocal $1/f:X \to 1/Y$. (Here, "$1/Y$" denotes the set of reciprocals of elements of $Y$. Consequently, $X = Y = 1/Y$: The domain and target of $f$ are the same set, and are closed under taking reciprocals, and $0$ is not an element of $X$.)

At the level of elements, for all $x$ in $X$ and $y$ in $Y$,
$y = f(x)$ if and only if
$$
x = f^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{f(y)}.
\tag{1}
$$

Substituting $y = f(x)$ in (1) and taking reciprocals,
$$
f^{[2]}(x) := f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)
  = \frac{1}{x}\quad\text{for all $x$ in $X$.}
\tag{2}
$$
Applying $f$ to both sides and using associativity of composition,
$$
f^{[3]}(x) = f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{f(x)}\quad\text{for all $x$ in $X$.}
\tag{3}
$$
One more application of $f$ gives
$$
f^{[4]}(x) = f^{[2]}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = x\quad\text{for all $x$ in $X$.}
\tag{4}
$$
That is, $f$ generates an action of the cyclic group of order $4$ on $X$. Further, each point $x$ in $X$ "generates" a square in which the solid arrows denote application of $f$, and the dashed arrows represent application of the reciprocal function ($x \mapsto 1/x$).

[image: Pointwise action of a map whose reciprocal is its inverse]

Such functions certainly *exist* (modulo the axiom of choice, depending how large you want the domain $X$ to be); just pick distinct complex numbers $a$ and $b$ other than $0$, $1$, and $-1$, place $a$, $b$, $1/a$, and $1/b$ cyclically around the corners of such a square, and define $f$ according to the diagram. (You can also consistently define $f(1) = 1$ and/or $f(-1) = -1$, or $f(1) = -1$ and $f(-1) = 1$. These numbers are special because they're fixed by the reciprocal function itself.)

---

The question remains: *Does any such function have an explicit algebraic formula?* Offhand I don't know.

The function proposed in the comments, $f(x) = x^{i} = \exp(i\log x)$ with $\log$ denoting the principal branch, does not work without qualification: For $x > 0$ real,
$$
f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)
  = \exp\bigl(i\log(\exp i\log x)\bigr)
  \neq \exp(-\log x)
  = \frac{1}{x}
$$
unless $\log(\exp i\log x) = i\log x$, which happens if and only if $\exp(i\log x)$ has absolute argument less than $\pi$, if and only if $e^{-\pi} < x < e^{\pi}$.

The formula $f(x) = \exp(i\log x)$ *does* work on any reciprocal-invariant, $f$-invariant set. No real interval has this property, however, since $f$ is not real-valued on any real interval. Every open disk with $a > 0$ and $1/a$ lying on a diameter is reciprocal-invariant, but a bit of numerical experimentation suggests no such disk is $f$-invariant. (I haven't carefully checked.)

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$ g(x)=  \frac{I}{1!} x  -\frac{1 + I}{2!} x^{2}  
+\frac{3 + I}{3!} x^{3}  -\frac{10}{4!} x^{4}
+\frac{40 - 10I}{5!} x^{5}  -\frac{190 - 90I}{6!} x^{6}\\
  +\frac{1050 - 730I}{7!} x^{7}  -\frac{6620 - 6160I}{8!} x^{8}  
+\frac{46800 - 55900I}{9!} x^{9}  -\frac{365300 - 549900I}{10!} x^{10}  \\
+\frac{3103100 - 5864300I}{11!} x^{11}  -\frac{28269800 - 67610400I}{12!} x^{12} \\
 +\frac{271627200 - 839594600I}{13!} x^{13}  -\frac{2691559000 - 11186357000I}{14!} x^{14} \\
 +\frac{26495469000 - 159300557000I}{15!} x^{15}\\
  + O(x^{16})
$$
and $f(x) = g(x-1)+1$ 
then $$f(f(x)) = \frac{1}{x} \\ f(x)=\frac{1}{f°^{-1}(x)} \\ f°^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)} $$ for $x-1$ in the range of convergence of $g(x)$.

(The range of convergence can be extended by Eulersummation as far as the resulting signs in $g(x)$ alternate, that means effectively for $f(x)$ with $x \gt -1$)

---

The function $g(x)$ has been constructed by the idea that 
$$  g°^2(x) = \exp(-1 \cdot \log(1+x))-1 \\
g(x) = \exp( i \cdot \log(1+x))-1  \\
$$ which has also already been suggested by earlier answers as well.
One can use Pari/GP with the function-call  `serlaplace(exp(I*log(1+x))-1)` to get the coefficients for the function $g(x)$