# How to find an a function whose inverse is also its multiplicative inverse?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

I'm looking for a function $f(x)$ so that $f_{inv}(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$. Does such a function exist and if so, how do I find it?

Comment: What's the domain of $f$? There's always the trivial example $f: \{1\} \rightarrow \{1\}, 1 \mapsto 1$.

Comment: Let us focus on the set of monotonic functions. If $f$ is increasing (decreasing) then $f_{\text{inv}}$ is also increasing (decreasing), however $\frac 1{f(x)}$ is decreasing (increasing). Hence such a function does not exist.

Comment: Here is an [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585394/120540) which is very similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function whose inverse is exactly the reciprocal of the function, that is $f^{-1} = \frac{1}{f}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585394/is-there-a-function-whose-inverse-is-exactly-the-reciprocal-of-the-function-tha)

Comment: Yeah, I had searched first but without the term "reciprocal". Thanks for the help

Comment: that would mean $x = f^{-1}(f(x)) = \frac 1{f(x)}$ so $f(x) = \frac 1x$.