# Functional equation: what function is its inverse's reciprocal?

Tags: inverse, functional-equations, inverse-function

The fact that so many students confuse functional inverse notation
$$f^{-1}(x)$$
with multiplicative inverse notation
$$[f(x)]^{-1}$$
got me to thinking... does there exist a function whose inverse is its inverse? That is, is there a function $f:\mathbb R_+\mapsto \mathbb R_+$ whose functional inverse is also its multiplicative inverse, so that
$$f^{-1}(x)=[f(x)]^{-1}, \space\space\space \forall x\in\mathbb R_+$$
Any ideas? I'll impose the restriction of continuity to deter nasty solutions.

Comment: Well, since $\frac1{f(f(x))}=x$, necessarily domain and range of $f$ cannot contain $0$. At best, then, $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli But with the requirement of continuity, it can only go from half of the real line to the other half.

Comment: @HansLundmark: This question imposes the restriction of continuity, whereas the other question you link to does not, so this does not seem to be a duplicate. Sammy Black's answer to the other question does consider differentiability, but even that is not (quite) a duplicate.

Comment: There were also some other similar posts: [A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897113) or [When is $f^{-1}=1/f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/260278) However, the domain is $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, respectivelly. Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f%5E%7B-1%7D(x)%3D%5Cfrac1%7Bf(x)%7D%24&p=2).

Comment: In fact, despite the question stating that it is about functions on $\mathbb C$, the paper mentioned [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260278/when-is-f-1-1-f/260283#260283) might be interesting in connection with functions defined in $(0,\infty)$. (Russell Euler and James Foran. "On Functions Whose Inverse Is Their Reciprocal." 
 *Mathematics Magazine*
Vol. 54, No. 4 (Sep., 1981), pp. 185-189. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689629)

Comment: To avoid any ambiguity between the reciprocal and the inverse, one may write $$f^{-1}$$ for the reciprocal and $$\mathop f^{-1}$$ for the inverse.

Comment: I have just added an explicite display of a power series which provides a computable solution in a range of convergence in the linked earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2593917/1714 . Perhaps this is of interest here.

Comment: @Michael - a fairly frequent notation which I like most uses the circle $\circ$ (from the notational scheme for function composition) to put it as superscript $f°^{-1}(x)$ for the (functional/compositional) inverse. Then  $f^{-1}(x)$ or better (because more common) $f(x)^{-1}$ (or even with the "hat" as superscript $f\hat \; ^{-1}(x)$) is for the multiplicative inverse(reciprocal)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, it is impossible.

If $f: (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ is continuous and $f^{-1}$ exists, then $f$ is either increasing or decreasing.  If $f$ is increasing, $f^{-1}$ is increasing but $1/f$ is decreasing.  If $f$ is decreasing, $f^{-1}$ is decreasing but $1/f$ is increasing.

EDIT: However, for $f: \mathbb R \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$ it is possible.  Take

$$ f(x) = \cases{ -x & if $x > 0$\cr
                 -1/x & if $x < 0$\cr} $$

Comment: Nicely done! $\space$

Comment: The linked thread gives a (discontinuous) example $f: (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 8):

Call $g=\ln\circ f\circ \exp:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Then, $g^{-1}=\ln\circ f^{-1}\circ \exp=\ln\frac1{f\circ \exp}=-g$.

So, we want the homeomorphisms $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $g^{-1}=-g$. But the homeomorphism $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are strictly monotone continuous functions. And, if $g$ is strictly monotone, $g^{-1}$ must be monotone of the same sign. This is not consistent with $g^{-1}=-g$. Thus, there is no such $g$ and no such $f$.